# MS CRM c#: Pickup string guid from dictionary and use it to populate lookup field when creating a new CRM record

Tags: c#, guid, dynamics-crm-4

I'm a total newbie to C#.  Trying to create a custom entity record. I have created a windows service that can connect and create the CRM custom entity record  but only if I hard code the GUID's for the lookups.

How can I pickup the GUID from the dictionary and turn it into a lookup like I do for the text fields? snippet is below.

```
aar_assessmentresult aar_assessmentresult = new aar_assessmentresult();
foreach (string key in dicColumnList.Keys)
                    {
                        colVal = string.Empty;
                        if (dicColumnList.TryGetValue(key, out colVal))
                        {

                            //this works
                            if (key.ToString() == "AssessmentResultName")
                            {
                                aar_assessmentresult.aar_name = colVal.Replace("'", "''");
                            }

                            //Code breaks here                               
    if (key.ToString() == "ContactID")
                            {

                                Guid contactid = new Guid();
                                aar_assessmentresult.aar_contactid = new Lookup();
                                aar_assessmentresult.aar_contactid.type = "contact";
                                aar_assessmentresult.aar_contactid.Value = contactid;
                            }

                        }
                    }
 crmService.Create(aar_assessmentresult);
```

Comment: When you say "code breaks here", what happens exactly?

Answer (score 1):

when you do this:

```
Guid contactid = new Guid(); 
aar_assessmentresult.aar_contactid = new Lookup(); 
aar_assessmentresult.aar_contactid.type = "contact"; 
aar_assessmentresult.aar_contactid.Value = contactid;
```

you are trying to set a contact lookup with an invalid reference since your variable contactid does is not related to an existing contact record.
You must create the contact in before or refer to a valid existing contact before doing

```
crmService.Create(aar_assessmentresult);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. The Guid held in the dictionary is for a valid existing contact.  I just want to use this GUID to create the lookup to the contact.  Are you saying this is not possible without first retreiving the contact?